# Getting empty response from Microsoft Graph API Authorization Requst?

Tags: vbscript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting an empty response Microsoft Graph API although the status of request is 200.

I have been following this documentation. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

I successfully registered an app and got the ClientID.

I am using VBScript to create a GET Request - here is my code:

```
Dim oXMLHTTP
Dim oStream

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

oXMLHTTP.Open  "GET", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=######&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access+mail.read", False
oXMLHTTP.Send
wscript.echo oXMLHTTP.status
wscript.echo oXMLHTTP.responseBody
```

Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong?

oXMLHTTP.status = 200

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong the authorize request was successful, now call the API to do something. Reading the link it says - *"If the user consents to the permissions your app requested, the response will contain the authorization code in the code parameter. Here is an example of a successful response to the previous request. Because the response_mode parameter in the request was set to query, the response is returned in the query string of the redirect URL"*. So the response URL will contain the authorization code to pass in the querystring of the response URL.

Comment: Dear @Lankymart, thanks for reaching out. The response I am getting is empty.

Comment: That workflow expects a redirection to the redirect_url you provide during authorization think you want to try [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

Answer (score -1):

The process of using oauth code flow to obtain tokens and call api is as follows:

1. Enter this link in the browser to obtain the authorization code:

   ```
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/authorize?
    client_id={your-client-id}
    &response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=https://localhost:4500/web/completeoauth/ms
    &response_mode=query
    &scope=openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read
    &state=12345
   ```

[image]

[image]

2. Use code to get access token: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token).

For your question, it is recommended that you use MSAL.NET for authentication, which eliminates the step of obtaining `code`.

```
 Private Function Login() As Boolean

        Dim publicClientApp As IPublicClientApplication
        publicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(client_id).WithAuthority(authority).Build()

        Dim accounts As IEnumerable(Of IAccount) = publicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync().Result()
        Dim firstAccount As IAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim authResult As AuthenticationResult

        Try
            authResult = publicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync().Result()
        Catch e As MsalUiRequiredException
            Try
                authResult = publicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result()
            Catch ex As Exception
                'user cancelled
                Return False
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine($"Auth Exception: {ex.Message}")
            Return False
        End Try

        _accessToken = authResult.AccessToken

        Return True

    End Function
```

Please see:[VB.NET – USE MSAL.NET IN A CONSOLE APPLICATION TO AUTHENTICATE TO AZURE](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/12/vb-net-use-msal-net-in-a-console-application-to-authenticate-to-azure/)

Comment: Check the tags, the OP is using [tag:vbscript] not [tag:vb.net] or any [tag:.net] for that matter.